# How can I create a small relational database in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I need to make a small database in MySQL that has two tables.

Clothes and ClotheType

Clothes has: ID, Name, Color, Brand, Price, ClotheTypeID
ClotheType has: ID, Description

In Microsoft SQL it would be:

```
create table Clothes(
id int,
primary key(id),
name varchar(200),
color varchar(200),
brand varchar(200),
price varchar(200),
clothetypeid int,
foreign key clothetypeid references ClotheType(id)
)
```

I need this in MySQL.

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?  Did you get an error?  What error did you get?

Comment: In case you misunderstood my question, I that code example is for Microsoft SQL, I want something similar for MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table Clothes(
    id int,
    primary key(id),
    name varchar(200),
    color varchar(200),
    brand varchar(200),
    price varchar(200),
    clothetypeid int,
    constraint `constr_Clothes_clothetypeid_fk` foreign key `clothetypeid_fk` (`clothetypeid`) references `ClotheType`(`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

NB.

- id must be an indexed column in table `ClotheType`, and it must have the same type (i.e. int)
- `ClotheType` must also be `ENGINE=INNODB`. If you have already created it then you can change it using `ALTER TABLE ClotheType ENGINE=INNODB`

To answer the question you posed in your comment on Ólafur's answer: MySQL handles foreign key constraints natively in as much as it parses the relevant data definition language statements, but some of its storage engines do not support them. The default storage engine in most MySQL installations is MyISAM, which does not support foreign keys. InnoDB does support them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InnoDB database engine in MySQL (instead of the default MyISAM), it has foreign key constraints.

Here is the MySQL documentation entry on the [InnoDB Foreign Key Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: Then how does MySQL handle relations natively?

Comment: It depends on the database engine you use. With MyISAM, there are no relations. InnoDB is a relational database engine within MySQL.